# How to use oAuth acquired credentials in background service?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am following this (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) to use Google calendar APIs in my Android app.

It works, however I need to be able to do the same in a background service.

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
                transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName("Google Calendar API Android Quickstart")
                .build();
```

helps me instantiate the calendar object.

I instantiate crendential like so:

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
```

How do I use them both in my background service?

I am using IntentService (WakefulIntentService) as a background service.

The intent service is triggered from an alarm like this:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int PERIOD = 5000;
    private static final int INITIAL_DELAY = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {
        if (i.getAction() == null) {
            WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(ctxt, ScheduledService.class);
        } else {
            scheduleAlarms(ctxt);
        }
    }

    static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
        AlarmManager mgr =
                (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, Receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctxt, 0, i, 0);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + INITIAL_DELAY,
                PERIOD, pi);
    }
}
```

My main activity calls `Receiver.scheduleAlarms`.